# JSONException: Index 0 out of range [0..0)

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to calculate the route between two locations with a code that you already know.
In my case the first location is MY location and the second location is the nearest LatLng
of a path.

This code below calculates the nearest LatLng:

```
private LatLng nearestLatLng(Location mCurrentLocation) {

    LatLng latLngCurrentLocation = new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
    double nearestLatitude = 0;
    double nearestLongitude = 0;
    float minDistance = 1000; //I don't know how to initialize 
    float currentDistance;

    for(int i=0; i<mLatLngGpxList.size(); i++) {
        LatLng currentTrackLatLng = mLatLngGpxList.get(i);
        currentDistance = getDistance(latLngCurrentLocation, currentTrackLatLng);
        if(currentDistance <= minDistance) {
            minDistance = currentDistance;
            nearestLatitude = currentTrackLatLng.latitude;
            nearestLongitude = currentTrackLatLng.longitude;
        }
    }

    //mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(nearestLatitude, nearestLongitude)));
    return new LatLng(nearestLatitude,nearestLongitude);
}

//Calcola la distanza tra due LatLng
private float getDistance(LatLng first, LatLng second) {
    float [] dist = new float[1];
    Location.distanceBetween(first.latitude, first.longitude, second.latitude, second.longitude, dist);
    return dist[0];
}
```

If i draw a path in my country, i can also draw the path for reach it, but if i draw a path
away from my country, i get this:

```
org.json.JSONException: Index 0 out of range [0..0)
at org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:263)
at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:480)
```

etc.

and consequently no path to my path is drawn. Why? :(

Ps: i DON'T get "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API."

Update: the error is in the code above. Advice? :/

Second Update: float minDistance = 1000; --> became float minDistance = 100000000
and now works. It remains a logical problem but i'll see.. :/

Comment: float minimumDiatance = 1000f; otherwise it consider as double.

Comment: from where you fetch json data. and what is mLatLngGpxList.